# Border along the edges of the screen

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to create a view that is place on top of a view controller that has border around the edges of the screen. On old iPhone models (pre-iPhone X), this was easy, you would add a view with a border. Now that the newer iPhone models have a notch and rounded corners, creating such a view seems impossible.

I've tried adding borders to UIView, but the iPhone's notch and rounded rectangles cut off and hide the border.

```
    let customView = UIView(frame: view.frame)
    customView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white
    customView.layer.borderWidth = 1
    customView.layer.cornerRadius = 30
    view.addSubview(customView)
```

I would like my view to have borders around the edges of the phone, no matter what device is being used.

If more information is required, leave it in the comments section and I will address them as soon as I can.

Comment: How do you want to handle the notch and rounded corners of the iPhone X? Why not set your border view's frame to be within the safe area of the view controller's view?

Comment: I want the border to curve (while stuck) to the notch, not behind it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you will get any help from UIKit in pulling this off, Apple would rather devs code without direct consideration for the notch or rounded corners and instead respect the safe areas provided by UIKit. You could try drawing some custom lines based on the device information but it will be difficult and you risk a rejection from Apple.

> Don't mask or call special attention to key display features. Don't
>   attempt to hide a device's rounded corners, sensor housing, or
>   indicator for accessing the Home screen by placing black bars at the
>   top and bottom of the screen. Don't use visual adornments like
>   brackets, bezels, shapes, or instructional text to call special
>   attention to these areas, either.

https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/visual-design/adaptivity-and-layout/

Comment: There can easily be a legitimate reason to draw such a border, if you are making a game and the game design calls for it.